# How can i append prefix value to all elements using yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

.Yaml file

```
- op: replace
  path: /data/app1
  value: appone
- op: replace
  path: /data/app2
  value: apptwo
- op: replace
  path: /data/app3
  value: appthree
```

...... likewise N number of apps

So i wanted to run yq command to replace all value field and include some prefix
Ex-

```
- op: replace
      path: /data/app1
      value: prefix-appone
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample yaml input data. Also, please specify [which yq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) you are using.

Comment: In the future, please properly format your code samples: this makes them much easier to read. I have taken care of the formatting in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using [the same version of `yq` that I am using](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), you could write this:

```
yq -y  '[.[]|.value |= "prefix-" + .]' < data.yaml
```

Which given your sample input produces as output:

```
- op: replace
  path: /data/app1
  value: prefix-appone
- op: replace
  path: /data/app2
  value: prefix-apptwo
- op: replace
  path: /data/app3
  value: prefix-appthree
```

Comment: Is this simpler ? `'.[].value |= "prefix-" + .'`

Comment: Sure, that looks better.